# Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. SQL server database mail

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I tried to send mail via sql server 2016 mail wizard i added all the profile and the account properly, but its throwing following error

> Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object..

Comment: That error message means that something is missing.  If you want more than that you'll need to ask a question and provide some details.

Comment: I added the profile and the the gmail account with smtp.gmail.com and the port number 587 and also checked the SSL and i checked the basic authentication and provide the username and password in that fields